# Why don't AngularJS $resources resolve on my machine?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have an AngularJS application that is running reliably on production and has no problems on my coworker's development machines. But when the app runs on my MacBook, it freezes after the first API call.

Here's what I see:

1. UI interactions are executing controller functions.
2. Functions are calling factory functions like `Company.get()` and passing in parameters, success callback, and error callback as arguments.
3. The `$resource` instances inside the factories are triggering network requests.
4. These network requests look successful in the browser dev panel (200 response with correct data).
5. Neither callback is ever triggered.
6. The app remains in a *loading* state until the page is refreshed.

Again, #5 & #6 only occur when run in a dev environment on my machine (specs below). The production website runs fine in the same browser. Code from the same git commit has no problems on my coworkers' machines.

So, this would seem to be an issue with what I have (or do not have) installed or configured on my machine. But, I can't seem to find anything out of the ordinary. The build process has no messages that seem related. I've rolled back my node version to match my coworker. I've deleted the entire repository to download and install fresh. I've restarted my computer. Nothing works. The best clue I've found is that `livereload` is also broken on my machine. But, it's not clear to me how that would be related.

I'd love to get some new ideas on how I might fix this.

My specs:
MacOS 11.2.2 Chrome 88
Node.js (I've tried versions 14, 10, 8)
AngularJS (including angular-resource) 1.5.8, grunt1.0.4 w/ CLI 1.3.2, grunt-express-server^0.5.3, bower 1.8.8, connect-livereload~0.6.0

Comment: angular-resource uses $http which uses XMLHttpRequest ... so onload is executed or not?

Comment: I'm not sure which onload you mean. For window/document? The app is mostly working (navigation, etc.). It's only API calls that fail.

I tried replacing the factory with `$http.get(url).then(cb)`. As above, the dev console showed a good API response, but the callback was never executed.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest.onload -- this is native callback which in the end results in your angularjs callback, so you may check in debug if it is executed or not.

Comment: I'll take a look.